# Windows alternative to macOS os_signpost functions – posting custom markers in Intel VTune or VS Profiler

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2019, profiler, intel-vtune

On macOS the `os_signpost` functions can be used to create markers that appear in the timeline of the XCode Instruments profiler. This is extremely helpful to spot certain events in a profiling session.

For cross-platform C++ applications, I‘d like to have the same feature on Windows, where I either use Intel VTune or the Visual Studio 2019 profiler. Is there an API allowing something similar with at least one of these profilers on Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Instrumentation and Tracing Technology APIs in VTune . Please refer the below link for more details : https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/vtune-help/top/api-support/instrumentation-and-tracing-technology-apis.html

Comment: Great news, didn’t know of that API, seems to be excactly what I was looking for. So in order to mark a region that shows up in a profiling session, `__itt_mark_pt_region` is the equivalent call?

Comment: https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/vtune-help/top/api-support/instrumentation-and-tracing-technology-apis/basic-usage-and-configuration/instrumenting-your-application.html
__itt_task_begin() marks the beginning of a task.
__itt_task_end() marks the end of a task.
This may work I think.